# Sending props to stateless components in react native

Tags: properties, react-native, components

I am trying to send an image source and title to a custom-made stateless component in React Native, as props. (imageSource and Title)

the props.imageSource line is causing an error, any help appreciated. Here is the code in question:

```
const MainPageButton = (props) => {

    var imageSource = require({props.imageSource});

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Image source={imageSource} />
          <Text>{props.title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) instead:

```
const MainPageButton = ({imageSource, title}) => {

  var imageSource = require(imageSource);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Image source={imageSource} />
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

> var imageSource = require({props.imageSource});

with

> var imageSource = require(props.imageSource);

props.imageSource will give you string which is enough for you to use